# realize the meaning of prometheus metrics increase and rate of counter?

Tags: python, request, prometheus

I want to get count of requests coming to my web application using `prometheus`, but I don't realize the numbers of the graph?

In my case I used both

`increase(search_all_view_counter_total{instance='localhost:8802', job='node_exporter_metrics'}[1m])`

and

`60 * (sum(rate(search_all_view_counter_total{instance='localhost:8802', job='node_exporter_metrics'}[1m])) by (instance))`

to get count of requests per minutes, in both case I got this result:

[image]

The graph shows the numbers go up to 8 or 9 while I only increased the counter 3 times in my web application code. why is this happening?